# text is not coming at the bottom of the screen

Tags: android

HI , why my text is not coming at the bottom evethough i have given  tParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
Here is my code please help,

```
 footScroll_relative = new RelativeLayout(this);
    footScroll_scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
    footScroll_horizontalScrollView = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
    test_text = new TextView(this);

    footScroll_relative.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    LayoutParams tParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    tParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    footScroll_horizontalScrollView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    footScroll_scrollView.setLayoutParams(tParams);

    test_text.setText("Ramesh ");

    footScroll_horizontalScrollView.addView(test_text);
    footScroll_scrollView.addView(footScroll_horizontalScrollView);
    footScroll_relative.addView(footScroll_scrollView);
    setContentView(footScroll_relative);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of how to

```
TextView tView = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.seekBarFilterLabel));
LayoutParams tParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
tParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
tView.setLayoutParams(tParams);
```

Hope this helps

EDIT: well, in your previuos unedited question you ask how to align the text at a RelativaLayout parent bottom, but here you are adding the TextView inside a HorizontalScrollView, wich is incorrect, the rule RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM are only valid if you are adding a view inside a RelativeLayout, not inside of ScrollView.

Comment: Yes, i have changed the code,but still not getting my desired output  lin = new LinearLayout(this);
        test_text = new TextView(this);
        LayoutParams tParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        tParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        lin.setLayoutParams(tParams);
        test_text.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        test_text.setText("Ramesh "); Please Help ?